# New Posts and Pages Won't Save

Tags: posts, pages

I haven't been able to save posts for the last week. When I try to add a new post, I can add the title just fine, and I can type the post, but none of the post text saves when I click Save Draft. I also see an empty post when I click Preview. The same thing is happening with Pages, too, and I can't upload images. I haven't added any new plugins. The only change I made was adding a file to the root directory through my host, but I tried deleting that and the problem persisted.

I've tried:
-updating themes and plugins

-logging out and logging back in

-clearing browser (Chrome) cache

-using a different browser and going incognito

Thanks!

Comment: did you try, just in case, to disable your plugins?

Comment: I didn't try it, but it worked just now! Thank you so much! Now to play process of elimination to find the culprit...

Comment: I'll post as answer.  Would you then hit the check mark to close the question out as answered?

Answer (score 1):

More often than not this is caused by a plugin update or incompatibility.  I would suggest disabling all your plugins and trying again.  Then re-enable a few at a time until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache and disabling plugins doesnt help then you can do what i did. Most at times we copy content from another source to paste in the editor instead of just typing it in. Some of these text include hidden incoding that the Json file cannot process so it breaks when it reads through the data you are saving so i solved the issue after trying other methods and failing by simply pasting any content i wish to paste in into a notepad then from there to the editor and thats it.

if you copy a text with horizontal lines in it and paste in editor you notice it pasted with the line which indicates the source code is held to the text, put pasting into a notpad will remove the line or image and alignments which indicates disassociation to the source code. Now its plain text and good to go. Save and enjoy!